# When page is loading ajax not response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have progress bar, I t work only when page is not loading, If page loading for example inserting data to database progressbar not, work only when finish inserting data, what is wring with my code ?

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {  
// 

    setInterval(function()  
        { 
    $.get("currentProgress.php", {  

    }, 
        function(data)    
            { 

    $('#progress_bar').width(data +"%");
    $('#progress_completed').html(parseInt(data) +"%"); 

            } 
        )},1000);  

}); 


</script>
```

In php loop: `$_SESSION['value'] +=1;`

And in currentProgress.php: `<?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['value']; ?>`

Comment: ajax normally works like that - the callback function only runs when the process called by get is finished.

Comment: what to do in my situation ?

Comment: @user2287965 could you explain a bit more "work only when finish inserting data" and share a brief code explanation of the "php loop"?

Comment: @laconbass sorry getting info from db and `while` lopp, and when displaying data in while loop progressbar is not updating for me, when finish inserting only then update progress bar with finish value

Comment: @user2287965 - going by your description, there wouldn't need a progress bar. By the time you send back progress information, your DB data has been accessed and returned. Unless there's an enormous amount of data to return?